# How to iterate an infinite animation with delays between iteration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am looking to iterate an infinite animation created with animate css by adding delay between iteration.

To achieve this i tried many option. The first one is to use plain javascript

HTML

`<div id="item" class=""></div>`

TS

```
       setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("item").toggleClass("animated tada" }, 3000);
)
```

I know this is not ideal for angular but this was the first way that came to my mind but i cant resolve the error the gave me which is

`Property 'toggleClass' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

I looked around and found that this could be the way

```
        let animation = (<HTMLScriptElement> document.getElementById("animated")).toggleClass();
      }, 3000);
```

Unfortunately the error persist even using this syntax.

So i moved on and I decide use ng-class

HTML
`[ngClass]="{'animated': !isAnimated, 'tada': !isAnimated}"`

TS
`setInterval(function(){ this.isAnimated = !this.isAnimated }3000);`

This cause to trigger the animation just once cause ng class got checked just once.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass` is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and you aren't using jQuery. Use `document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('myclass')` instead.